# Setting up VLANs using GS724T & Draytek 2860n-Plus

Tags: switch, vlan, smart, netgear, draytek

I am having a world of problems here and can't see what is going wrong!

## **The Plan:**

Use the Draytek to connect to the internet and provide WLAN access.
Single port to connect to the GS724T and tag VLANs.
Configure ports to belong to a particular VLAN, devices on a VLAN can communicate with each other and the Draytek only. If device is connected to a port belonging to VLAN2 the router provides an IP from LAN2
**Optional:** Each SSID to be on a different subnet to isolate traffic.

## **The failed setup:**

I have set up VLANs on the Draytek using the same IDs that I used on the Netgear. I think it is best if I post screenshots of the relevant sections so you can see what I have tried.

Screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4nLY.jpg

On the Port PVID Configuration page I tried changing ports 2-6 so the configured PVID was set to 20 but this resulted in no network access as I had a 169.x.x.x IP. If I manaually set my IP it still had no network access. The same result is seen if I uncheck any port from the general VLAN (VID 1).

I don't mind all IPs on the same subnet as long as devices can't communicate with devices in another VLAN. I would like devices connecting to the router wirelessly to have access to wired devices which are part of the same VLAN i.e. printing from an iPad to a networked printer.

Help would be much appreciated, I am sure I am missing something simple!

Thanks

Comment: Reading this it appears I am setting it up correctly but oddly enough when I assign a port to a VLAN it is not automatically removed from the default VLAN1. When I manually unassign it from VID1 I cannot get an IP. http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8898/~/2-vlans-accessing-internet-using-layer-2-switch-%26-router

Answer (score 0):

Ok well after a lot of frustration I reset the Draytek to factory settings and configured the VLAN section again, this time I only used LAN1 for subnets. Everything worked perfectly... I will be adding subnets soon to test as remote dial-in users will have to be isolated too but happy I got it working. Not sure what caused the strange behavious as I then reconfigured the rest of the router the same as before and it continued to work.